# How to use OPENXML to load XML data into existing SQL Table?

Tags: t-sql, openxml

I am a newbie to OPENXML.  But I am trying to load a .XML file into a SQL table that I created for this.  I do not receive any errors with this code, but it doesn't insert any records either.  This is the table I created in 2008 SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE HOMEROOM(
HOMEROOM_TEACHER INT,
HOMEROOM_NUMBER INT,
ENTITY_ID INT)
```

And this is the T-SQL code I am trying to execute:

```
DECLARE @idoc int
DECLARE @xmlDocument varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Status INT

SET @xmlDocument ='
<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
  <s:Schema id="RowsetSchema">
    <s:ElementType name="row" content="eltOnly">
      <s:AttributeType name="c0" rs:name="HOMEROOM-TEACHER" rs:number="1" rs:nullable="true">
        <s:datatype dt:type="int" dt:maxLength="4" rs:precision="10" rs:fixedlength="true" />
      </s:AttributeType>
      <s:AttributeType name="c1" rs:name="HOMEROOM-NUMBER" rs:number="2">
        <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="10" rs:maybenull="false" />
      </s:AttributeType>
      <s:AttributeType name="c2" rs:name="ENTITY-ID" rs:number="3">
        <s:datatype dt:type="string" rs:dbtype="str" dt:maxLength="10" rs:maybenull="false" />
      </s:AttributeType>
      <s:extends type="rs:rowbase" />
    </s:ElementType>
  </s:Schema>
  <rs:data>
    <z:row c0="22943" c1="101" c2="055" />
    <z:row c0="22929" c1="102" c2="055" />
    <z:row c0="22854" c1="103" c2="055" />
    <z:row c0="22908" c1="104" c2="055" />
    <z:row c0="22881" c1="105" c2="055" />
<z:row c0="22926" c1="Gym2" c2="055" />
<z:row c0="22935" c1="Gym3" c2="055" />
  </rs:data>
</xml>
'
EXEC @Status = sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlDocument
SELECT 'sp_xml_preparedocument status=',@Status

select *
FROM   OPENXML (@idoc, '/xml/',1)
         WITH    (
            HOMEROOM_TEACHER          INT    '@C0'
            ,HOMEROOM_NUMBER          VARCHAR(10) '@C1'
            ,ENTITY_ID          VARCHAR(10) 'C2'
                )

--sp_xml_removedocument @idoc

SELECT * FROM HOMEROOM
```

But after I execute this, I get 0 rows added to HOMEROOM.  Any suggestions for how to make this work?

When I execute above, I get error:
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 627
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Gym2' to data type int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXEC @Status = sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, 
@xmlDocument, '<xml xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" 
       xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
       xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" 
       xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema"/>' 
SELECT 'sp_xml_preparedocument status=',@Status 

SELECT * 
FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/xml/rs:data/z:row',1) 
WITH ( 
   HOMEROOM_TEACHER   INT    '@c0' 
  ,HOMEROOM_NUMBER    INT    '@c1' 
  ,ENTITY_ID          INT    '@c2' 
)
```

I did a few things:

1. Added the namespace declaration as
   the third parameter to
   sp_xml_preparedocument.
2. Changed the xpath section from '/xml/' to '/xml/rs:data/z:row' to specify the correct position and namespaces in the XML document
3. Changed the @C variables to lower case (@c)

Results were:

```
HOMEROOM_TEACHER HOMEROOM_NUMBER ENTITY_ID
---------------- --------------- -----------
22943            101             55
22929            102             55
22854            103             55
22908            104             55
22881            105             55
```

FYI, information about using OPENXML with namespaces can be found [here](http://sqlxml.org/faqs.aspx?faq=66).

Comment: I love this solution!  Yes, you caught all of my mistakes.  Now this is working for me.  Thank you so much!  You are great!

Comment: Hey, I was mistaken.  It didn't add any of this data to my table because it turns out I have two varchar fields instead.  So I'm getting error above.  I have updated my description also with new data.  Could you please have another look?

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to recreate the table with VARCHARS.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would use SQL Server 2005 XQuery over OPENXML - seems easier and cleaner to me.

Second of all - not entirely clear which elements or attributes you want to extract....

Third: you're ignoring the XML namespaces, that's why nothing is working.... they're there for a reason, and you need to pay attention to them!

So I tried something like this here:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '.....'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' AS rs, '#RowsetSchema' AS z)
SELECT
    Nodes.Attr.value('(@c0)[1]', 'INT') AS 'HomeroomTeacher',
    Nodes.Attr.value('(@c1)[1]', 'INT') AS 'HomeroomNumber',
    Nodes.Attr.value('(@c2)[1]', 'INT') AS 'EntityID'
FROM
    @input.nodes('/xml/rs:data/z:row') AS NOdes(Attr)
```

and I'm getting an output of:

```
HomeroomTeacher  HomeroomNumber  EntityID
   22943              101           55
   22929              102           55
   22854              103           55
   22908              104           55
   22881              105           55
```

This might not yet be exactly what you're looking for, but it might be a starting point!

I did:

- define the relevant XML namespaces `rs:` and `z:` using thte `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` construct
- created a "pseudo-table" `Nodes` with a pseudo-column `Attr` which basically has one row of XML for each elements that matches that XPath expression
- I then reach into those rows in the pseudo table and I'm able to pull out the relevant bits of information I need

Comment: Thanks Marc, I didn't try your solution but it looks like it would work well.  I have attribute-centric data.  I didn't understand before how to declare namespaces, but now I do.  Do u know which is more efficient on the server?  XQuery or OPENXML?

Comment: I'm sorry Marc, but I was mistaken.  I have two VARCHAR values and one INT.  I have updated my description with the error message.  Could you please have another look?

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to recreate the table with VARCHARS.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `INSERT INTO HOMEROOM (HOMEROOM_TEACHER, HOMEROOM_NUMBER, ENTITY_ID)` above your select and change your SELECT to `SELECT HOMEROOM_TEACHER ,HOMEROOM_NUMBER ,ENTITY_ID`.